# 2 divs in one place

Tags: html, css

I have divs with following CSS:

```
div{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    background:#2E2922;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

They are aligned in my HTML as a grid. I want second grid of divs that are placed in the same places a the first grid, and show themselves only when hovered. So, it's basically like: you see a picture in a div, hover over it, and instead of pic appears description inside a div. How to achieve it? No Frameworks, plz

Comment: So you want to achieve tooltip like functionality? When mouse overs on first div, second div will be shown in tooltip? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, something like it.

Comment: You should consider adding more details to your question.

Comment: Yes, I would add more details and show your full code. Make sure your question is clear and complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand your question, but here’s a solution to what I think you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/3Tb9T/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">Box #1</div>
    <div class="box box-on-hover">Box #1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">Box #2</div>
    <div class="box box-on-hover">Box #2.1</div>
  </div>
```

```
.boxes {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;    
    margin:10px;
}

.box {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:#2E2922;
    vertical-align:top;
    color: white;
}

.box-on-hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    background: red;
}

.wrapper:hover .box-on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

You can easily change the hover if you don’t want both boxes to change at the same time.

Comment: Yah, pretty much it. But when I applied it to my project i got this: http://jsfiddle.net/aaF6b/

Comment: Can you explain what will change on hover (style, content, both)? Maybe I have a better solution for you.

Comment: Well, I want to have an item (it will be a tf2 backpack browser) icon grid, and when you hover over an icon, it shows information about an item (name, flags, etc)

Comment: Okay, your fiddle is just missing a `z-index` value to make the `div1` appear above. http://jsfiddle.net/aaF6b/1/

Comment: Thanks! By the way, am I the only one who gets these little white round corners when I hover over this div?

Comment: No, it’s the browser rendering that is not so perfect. You can try to add the `border-radius` to the parent element with `overflow:hidden` instead of doing it for both children.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".one,.two").hover(function(){
       $(".two").hide();
  },function(){
       $(".two").show();
  });
```

[Check on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt9tD/)

I have put an example for you you have to make both div absolute and achieve the thing you want with a simple jquery code.

Check it in fiddle

Comment: This can be easily done with CSS, why do you introduce overkill JS here?

Comment: No need for JS/jQuery here. CSS can handle such basic functionality quite well on it's own

Answer (score 0):

You can place one `div` inside the other and use `position` and `display` attributes combined with `hover`:

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Uu3Hb/3/

### Code

```
<div id="outer">
    wazzup, doc!
    <div id="inner">
        I'm hidden until someones hover me  
    </div>
</div>

#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

#outer:hover #inner {
    display: block;
}
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more details refer this [forum link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-jquery-ui-tooltip-to-show-div-content)

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="subitem">Ready</div>
    <div class="subitem">Ready</div>
    <div class="subitem">Maintenance</div>
</div>
<div class="statusRollup">
    <p>Subitem 1: Nothing to report</p>
    <p>Subitem 2: Nothing to report</p>
    <p>Subitem 3: Scheduled maintenance</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('.subitem').attr('title', $('.statusRollup').remove().html())
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/ubKtd/)

Answer (score 0):

### *Here is pure HTML and CSS*

### HTML

```
<div style="z-index:2">
    abcd
    efgh
</div>
<div style="z-index:1">
    ijkl
    mnop
</div
```

### CSS

```
div{
    position:absolute;/*this is necessary.*/
    color:white;

    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    background:#2E2922;
    vertical-align:top;
}
div:hover+div, div:hover
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**FiddleDemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GdYg/)